# ElasticSearch aggregation over inner object

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ES I've a schema type like this:

```
{
  "index_v1":{
    "mappings":{
      "fuas":{
        "properties":{
          "comment":{
            "type":"string"
          },
          "matter":{
            "type":"string"
          },
          "metainfos":{
            "properties":{
              "department":{
                "type":"string"
              },
              "processos":{
                "type":"string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Shortly, `fuas` type has two properties `comment` and `matter` and an inner (not nested) object `metainfos` with several properties `department` and `processos`.

I'd like to know how many `metainfos' fields` are informed with its number of occurrences.

Imagine a document `doc1` with `metainfos: {department: "d1"}` and a `doc2` with `metainfos: {department: "d2", processos: "p1"}`.

Then I'd like to get: `{department: 2, processos: 1}`.

**EDIT**

As a inner object and since ES is schemaless documents' `metainfos` inner objects can have several fields informed or not.

So, `doc1's metainfos {field1: 1, field3: 3}` and `doc2's metainfos {field2: 1, field4: 5}` and `doc3's metainfos {field1:2, field4: 2, field5: 1}`.

I'd like to get: `{field1: 2, field2: 1, field3: 1, field4: 2, field5: 1}`. I think the main issue to solve it is how I'm able to ask for fields I don't know exist.

I've tested with two documents:

```
{
  "hits":{
    "total":2,
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_source":{
          "matter":"FUA2",
          "comment":null,
          "metainfos":[
            {
              "department":"d1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_source":{
          "matter":"FUA1",
          "comment":"vcvcvc",
          "metainfos":[
            {
              "department":"d1"
            },
            {
              "processos":"p1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tested this with this command:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9201/living_team/fuas/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.department" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "metainfos.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

The results have been:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.department" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`value_count` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) for this:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "dept" : { 
            "value_count" : { "field" : "metainfos.department" } 
        },
        "proc" : { 
            "value_count" : { "field" : "metainfos.processos" } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is I'm creating my mapping dynamically, so the fields of this innered object can change adding another field. So, I'd need some kind of additional aggregation in  order to be able to ask over whichever field existing in inner object.

Comment: I've already tried this. I've reported it on post. It seems something is wrong... Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested fields as otherwise your inner fields are not seen "together" in the metainfos object.

See here: [ElasticSearch aggregation over inner object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458724/elasticsearch-aggregation-over-inner-object)

Comment: I think this is another trouble. I believe which's the difference between inner (I mean "no nested") and nested objects. Nevertheless, do you think the last query is going to run correctly? Simply, using nested fields?

Comment: If you use nested_fields, you have to change the query or agg to use nested query or nested aggregation. Have a look at the reference, there should be some examples.